# Update mysql one table from another table based on dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a program for student attendance system and record save on mysql table like below if present then 1 and if absent then 0

Table -> attendance

```
uid  date       status  App
1   01/07/2013  1   
1   01/07/2013  1   
1   01/07/2013  1   
1   01/07/2013  0   
1   01/07/2013  0   
1   02/07/2013  1   
1   02/07/2013  0   
1   02/07/2013  1   
1   02/07/2013  1   
1   02/07/2013  1   
1   03/07/2013  0   
1   03/07/2013  0   
1   03/07/2013  1   
1   03/07/2013  1   
1   03/07/2013  1   
1   04/07/2013  0   
1   04/07/2013  1   
1   04/07/2013  1   
1   04/07/2013  1   
1   04/07/2013  1
```

And i also have a table where student submit their leave applications like below

Table -> application

```
 id  uid    from            to           status
 1   1    04/07/2013    07/07/2013  approved
 2   1    11/07/2013    12/07/2013  rejected
```

I want that if status sets to approved then the date range given in application from 4 july to 7 july will be searched on "attendance" table and whatever the dates will be found with 0 status it will add 1 to "app" column and ignore the  dates on which attendance is not taken.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You may want to set status to 2 IF status is 0, so you can reverse an application and still retain any normal attendance. Ie 0-off, 1-in, 2-hol

Comment: Your dates *are* stored using a `date` data type, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE attendance  d
  JOIN application p
    ON d.uid = p.uid
   AND d.date BETWEEN p.from AND p.to
   AND p.status = 'approved'
SET    d.app = 1
WHERE  d.status = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
UPDATE attendance  d
  JOIN application p
    ON d.uid = p.uid
   AND d.date BETWEEN p.from AND p.to
SET    d.status = 1
WHERE  p.status = 'approved'
```

Comment: It Should be D.App instead of d.status and also where clause with d.status = 0

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
UPDATE attendance a
    Set a.app=1
    WHERE a.uid IN
        (select z.uid
            FROM application z
            WHERE z.status='approved'
                AND a.date BETWEEN z.from and z.to);
```

Comment: @Waygood, I see why you think that but MySQL will do a row level match based on the correlated subquery. See the description of semi-joins here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/semi-joins.html.